# Realm of the mad god question about skin, cloths, and dyes

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

Right now, I have many skins, cloths, and dyes. I am worried that if I die, I would lose the skin, cloth, and the dye. I'm not sure if I die, I would still have the skin, cloth, and dye.

Comment: Partially answered here, for dyes, anyways: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53307/do-you-keep-dyes-permanently

Answer (score 1):

On death:

- All items on your character are lost (unless you store them in bank chest, obviously).
- Any character unlocks and progress are lost
- Account wide unlocks/features stay (such as characters and their looks).

Comment: For bank chest, do you mean vault?

Comment: @PennyBooks Yes

Answer (score 0):

Cloths and dyes will be lost after you die. But the is a cheap Fame Mystery Box for cloths and dyes. So you can get more if you die. Skins are **NOT** lost after you die, so you can be sure about that.